# Successful but Empty Result Fetched

Tags: sql

I am running this select statement in DbVisualizer and it says successful but there are no results. Ive been told there is a join issue, but I dont see any tables that arent joined.  Any help is appreciated!

```
select distinct e.display_employee, a.wfs_string9, tso.PPEND, a.OTHER_STRING13, tso.WORK_DT, tso.PPEND, tso.PAY_CODE, tso.HOURS
from employee e, asgnmt_master am, asgnmt a, time_sheet_output tso, employee_periods ep, employee_period_versions epv, pay_code pc
where pc.pay_code in (select record_key 
                    from rule_set rs, rule_set_detail rsd 
                    where rs.rule_set = rsd.rule_set 
                    and tso.work_dt between rs.eff_dt and rs.end_eff_dt 
                    and rs.source_table = 'PAY_CODE' and rs.rule_set IN ('BB_COUNTS_AS_HOURS_WORKED'))
and e.employee = am.employee
and am.asgnmt = a.asgnmt
and e.employee = ep.employee
and a.asgnmt = ep.asgnmt
and ep.pp_end between e.eff_dt and e.end_eff_dt
and ep.employee_period = epv.employee_period
and epv.employee_period_version = tso.employee_period_version
and tso.pay_code = pc.pay_code
and a.OTHER_STRING20 in ('Factory', 'Retail', 'Restaurant')
and a.OTHER_STRING1 = 'NonExempt'
and tso.ppend = '2020-03-14'
```

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.

Comment: Gordon - I joined all the tables here. and e.employee = am.employee
and am.asgnmt = a.asgnmt
and e.employee = ep.employee
and a.asgnmt = ep.asgnmt
and ep.pp_end between e.eff_dt and e.end_eff_dt
and ep.employee_period = epv.employee_period
and epv.employee_period_version = tso.employee_period_version
and tso.pay_code = pc.pay_code

Comment: Gordon means that you should use the explicit `join` syntax.  `from employee e join asgnmt_master am on e.employee = am.employee` ...

Comment: Hi Larry - Ive never used the syntax join, when I change AND to JOIN I get an error. 
 join e.employee = am.employee
and am.asgnmt = a.asgnmt
and e.employee = ep.employee
and a.asgnmt = ep.asgnmt
and ep.pp_end between e.eff_dt and e.end_eff_dt
and ep.employee_period = epv.employee_period
and epv.employee_period_version = tso.employee_period_version
and tso.pay_code = pc.pay_code
and a.OTHER_STRING20 in ('Factory', 'Retail', 'Restaurant')
and a.OTHER_STRING1 = 'NonExempt'
and a.OTHER_STRING22 = 'Y'
and tso.ppend = '2020-03-14'

Comment: @Bunky73 You forgot to add the `ON` clause, which is identical to what you added in your `WHERE` clause. The syntax you use is outdated (20 years or so, if I'm not mistaken) and could at any point be removed from the ANSI-SQL standard. .

Comment: Thanks @SchmitzIT, I have several other queries using the WHERE clause without issue.  I changed the clause WHERE to ON and received an error that its an incorrect syntax.

Comment: The comment by avery_larry shows you the correct syntax. `SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column = table2.column`. The part after `ON` is what you have in your `WHERE` clause. I.e. `SELECT * FROM from employee AS e INNER JOIN asgnmt_master AS am ON e.employee = am.employee`